# Java Threading and .sleep() confusion

Tags: java, multithreading, sleep, thread-sleep

Hi all sorry to bother you, I have a class in which I have implement runnable, I then have a run() method in which I run a small program at intervals using thread.sleep().- this works without any issue and runs the code periodically.

However I am confused on how to use thread.sleep() within other methods within my class, can someone prod me in the right direction?

apologies if simple in advance.

code example:

```
// Search product: returns list of matching titles
  public String[] find_titles(String title) throws RemoteException{
    try {
          Thread.sleep(5000);                                           //pause execution for 2s 
        } catch(InterruptedException e) {
          //error running the thread!
          System.exit(1);
    }
    ...
   }
```

Comment: Why would `Thread.sleep` be any different depending on where it is? Code is code.

Comment: because its not working mate!

Comment: Your code does nothing but put the current thread to sleep. If this is called in a background thread that does nothing else, your program will not experience any measurable changes in state. Without context your question is not answerable. For me, I am still completely confused as to exactly what it is you are asking. If the current answers answer your question, great, they're better at guessing than I am. If not, then you will want to improve your question by providing all the details necessary for us to understand your problem.

Comment: I don't want to put the code for the full method in there as it is part of a project for school so will be picked up by the school plagiarism software - humour me imagine there was simply a System.out.println("test"); underneath the thread.sleep - what imn finding is that the print would instantly happen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Thread.sleep()` is a static method in `Thread` class. That means it sleeps only current running thread.

As per `JavaDoc` of [Thread.sleep](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long%29) that says:

> Causes the currently executing thread to sleep (temporarily cease execution) for the specified number of milliseconds, subject to the precision and accuracy of system timers and schedulers. The thread does not lose ownership of any monitors.

Read more here about [Pausing Execution with Sleep](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sleep.html)

Now it depends where are you calling `Thread.sleep()` method that Thread will be sleep.

I hope its clear to you.

Answer (score 4):

`Thread.sleep()` will cause the current thread to sleep. If you use this in the main execution thread then your main program will pause and do nothing else. If your main thread invokes a runnable that thread will pause when it calls `Thread.sleep()` but your main thread, or any other threads will still be running.

Comment: see when I was using this in another method and called thread.sleep(5000) for example, the execution didn't seem to pause

Comment: @TotalNewbie in that case give a proper explanation along with some sample code.

Comment: Note that Thread.sleep(5000) is five thousand milliseconds or 5 seconds. That should be noticeable but if you were expecting 5000 seconds that would be quite different!